# Incorrect compare of strings in PHP with MySQl

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to compare today's date and the date of the last entry in the database. For some reason the code isn't working, and the comparison is always wrong.

```
$recentMood = mysqli_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM DemoUser ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1'");

   $today = date('Y-m-d');



   if($recentMood['date'] != $today){
      mysqli_query($db_connection, "INSERT INTO DemoUser (Mood, date) VALUES('$mood' , NOW())");
      echo "Mood recorded!";
   }

   else{


   echo "Mood already recorded.";
   }
```

P.S: When I try to echo either $today or $recentMood['date'], then I get an error. Any reason why that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing inside the if a resource to a date string.

```
if($recentMood['date'] != $today){
```

Fetch the results first:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM DemoUser ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1");
if($query->num_rows > 0) {
    $recentMood = $query->fetch_assoc(); // fetch it, you skipped this step
    $today = date('Y-m-d');

    $mood = $db_connection->real_escape_string($mood);
    if($recentMood['date'] != $today){
      mysqli_query($db_connection, "INSERT INTO DemoUser (Mood, date) VALUES('$mood' , NOW())");
      echo "Mood recorded!";
    } else {
        echo "Mood already recorded.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to make this work properly, you need to convert the date from the database into a usable timestamp.

```
if ($recentMood['date']) {
    $past_mood = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($recentMood['date']));
}
$today = date('Y-m-d');

if($past_mood != $today){
      mysqli_query($db_connection, "INSERT INTO DemoUser (Mood, date) 
                                    VALUES('$mood' , NOW())");
      echo "Mood recorded!";
}
```